# latin-1 codec can't encode charset in position 41-45: original not in range 256

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]пытаюсь из python  передать файл на vsftpd с русским названием файла. но получаю ошибку
 (latin-1 codec can't encode charset in position 41-45: original not in range 256) как мне все таки его передать?

код

```
if os.listdir("C:/users/{}/desktop/Auto_copy_folder".format(u_name)):
            file_date = os.listdir("C:/users/{}/desktop/Auto_copy_folder".format(u_name))
            for x in file_date:
                filename=('C:/users/{}/desktop/Auto_copy_folder/{}'.format(u_name,x))
                try:
                    ftp_login()
                except ftplib.Error as e:
                    print("Нет подключения")
                else:
                    FTP.cwd('/media/disk1/Auto_copy_folder')
                    f = open (filename, "rb")
                    try:
                        upload(filename,f)
                    except ftplib.Error as e:
                        print("Ошибка отправки файла", e)
                        f.close()
                        FTP.close()
                    else:
                        if FTP.size(filename.split('/')[-1]) == os.path.getsize(filename):
                            f.close()
                            FTP.close()
                            os.remove(filename)

                        else:
                            print("Данные переданы с ошибкой")
```

Comment: поменять название файла на нерусское???

Comment: как вы себе представляете авто переименовывание файлов?

Comment: данная программа пишется для пожилого человека который часто теряет жесткие с фотографиями и важными данными, поэтому переименовывать не вариант. Потом она найти ничего не сможет

Comment: транслит - и читается, и переименовать файлы на изи

Comment: а других способов нет?только переименовывать файл?

Comment: сделал через транслит, работает, спасибо за совет.

Comment: другие способы может и были, да только в сфере, в которой вы задали вопрос я не силен) предложил что придумал, хорошо что помогло)

Comment: Есть еще вариант не менять название файлов.
На Python-е  уже опробовал архивацию в zip-файл.
Доработайте программу на создание архива с латинским названием и потом передавайте.
Работа с такими архивами не представляет никакой сложности даже для не очень продвинутого пользователя.